# How to find already installed sql server 2014 instance name and version?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I am using code below to get all instance names and server names in my local machine.

```
private List<string> GetInstanceName()
    {
        var result = new List<String>();
        RegistryView registryView = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32;
        using (RegistryKey hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, registryView))
        {
            RegistryKey instanceKey = hklm.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL", false);

            if (instanceKey != null)
            {
                foreach (var instanceName in instanceKey.GetValueNames())
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(instanceName))
                    {
                        result.Add(instanceName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

But I need to get version also. i dont know how to get version for each instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the information you get from the registry key values in "Instance Names\SQL", you need to go back into the registry again and fetch the info you're looking for.

Try this code:

```
// find the installed SQL Server instance names
RegistryKey key = baseKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL");

// loop over those instances
foreach (string sqlInstance in key.GetValueNames())
{
    Console.WriteLine("SQL Server instance: {0}", sqlInstance);

    // find the SQL Server internal name for the instance
    string internalName = key.GetValue(sqlInstance).ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("\tInternal instance name: {0}", internalName);

    // using that internal name - find the "Setup" node in the registry
    string instanceSetupNode = string.Format(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\{0}\Setup", internalName);

    RegistryKey setupKey = baseKey.OpenSubKey(instanceSetupNode, false);

    if (setupKey != null)
    {
        // in the "Setup" node, you have several interesting items, like
        // * edition and version of that instance
        // * base path for the instance itself, and for the data for that instance
        string edition = setupKey.GetValue("Edition").ToString();
        string pathToInstance = setupKey.GetValue("SQLBinRoot").ToString();
        string version = setupKey.GetValue("Version").ToString();

        Console.WriteLine("\tEdition         : {0}", edition);
        Console.WriteLine("\tVersion         : {0}", version);
        Console.WriteLine("\tPath to instance: {0}", pathToInstance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable answer would be to use

```
DataTable instances = Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(local: true);
```

Comment: It was returning empty array